# GitKraken Crashes on Startup with no error

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, git

**The problem**
I am tryng to run gitkraken on Ubuntu 20.04.6. However whenever I go to open gitkraken nothing happens.

**Steps to reproduce**
Run the following commands to download and install:

```
gitkraken wget https://release.gitkraken.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb
sudo apt install gitkraken-amd64.deb
```

Then try to open gitkraken in either the terminal using `gitkraken` or from the activities menu.

Running `gitkraken` in the terminal provides no output, but running `gitkraken -v` does output the version number as shown below:

```
root@curtis-VirtualBox:~# gitkraken
root@curtis-VirtualBox:~# 
root@curtis-VirtualBox:~# gitkraken -v
9.11.1
root@curtis-VirtualBox:~#
```